# Chrome Remote Desktop issue under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, remote-desktop, chrome-extension

I have setup Ubuntu 20.04 with xfce4 and xfce4. It works, but is quite slow for 4K displays.

I'm trying to setup Chrome Remote Desktop instead. I installed both google-chrome-stable and chrome-remote-desktop packages.

When I try to setup the machine for remote access at
https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/, I get asked to name the machine, then for the PIN twice. After that, I get a mysterious and unhelpful "An unknown error has occurred" message in red.

I had this working yesterday in fact, but had to uninstall & reinstall Chrome, and now it no longer works. I don't have an OS backup, so I can't go back to the previous known good state.

Is there any kind of log anywhere that would provide more information about what the problem is besides "An unknown error has occurred".

Comment: In order to fix this I simply had to follow the instructions for starting the service from the command line on the Ubuntu server: Just go to: https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless
and follow the directions for starting the service Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I was able to search for "logs" to pull up the log file in Ubuntu.  I found that there was an issue reading the config folder for chrome-remote-desktop.  I updated the permissions for that folder to RWX and then setting up the pin worked

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190135)